# How to parse XML files using XPath with ESM in Node.js

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, xml

I am working on a task for work that involves using an XML file and needing to parse that file with XPath using .mjs files. I don't normally code using .mjs files and the data that I am typically working with is JSON. This is a legacy app that we are converting from C# to Node and we need to be able to parse XML files. The requirements are as follows:

Must use .mjs extension
Module must run in Node.js so it should not depend on any browser-specific JavaScript features
Module's default export should be an asynchronous function which crawls the directory tree and parses the XML files it finds

I am at a loss for even where to begin. Any assistance with pointing me in the right direction would be extremely helpful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you use a Power Shell script?

Comment: SaxonJS https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/index.xml exists in a Node.js version and allows doing XPath 3.1. I can't judge whether the "ESM" part in your question is any obstacle to using SaxonJS.

Comment: @jdweng I am not using a Power Shell script that I know of. I am just needing to write a Nodejs program that reads xml data from a file with a .xml extension and only a .xml extension using the EcmaScriptModules(ESM)

Comment: @MartinHonnen I am not running into issues where my code isn't working, I am running into issues just trying to start this project. I don't usually work with XML so I am not sure how to parse XML files with Node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give you a very simple example using XPath 3.1 with [SaxonJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/saxon-js) in an ESM module:

```
import { default as SaxonJS } from 'saxon-js';

const xml = `<root>
  <item>a</item>
  <item>b</item>
  <item>c</item>
</root>`;

const xmlDoc = await SaxonJS.getResource({ type: 'xml', text: xml });

console.log(SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate(`random-number-generator(current-dateTime())?permute(/root/item) => serialize(map { 'method' : 'xml', 'indent' : true() })`, xmlDoc));
```

Documentation is at https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation2/index.html